# Using len() with if/else to populate dataframe variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to add a variable to my dataframe that concatenates several other variables. I know that if variable 'do' is less that 4 characters, it is garbage input and I should instead use variable 'ra'. However, the below throws an attribute error: "AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'len'", 'occurred at index 0')". Is the apply operation the correct way to go about what I'm doing, and if so, how can I correct my function?

```
def get_combined(row):
    if row['do'].len() < 4:
        return row['ra']+' '+row['mi']+' '+row['fa']+' '+row['so']
    else:
        return row['do']+' '+row['mi']+' '+row['fa']+' '+row['so']

df['Combined'] = df.apply(get_combined, axis=1)
```

Comment: ... why do you think there should exist a `.len()` method???

Comment: I am attempting to use .len() to identify whether the data in a given index/variable is valid or not. This is a text field. If that text is less than 4 characters long, I know there is an issue with it and I don't want to use it.

Comment: That wasn't my question though, why do you imagine such a method exists at all? Is that somewhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The second line should be:

```
if len(row['do']) < 4:
```

Comment: Doing this yields a different error: TypeError: ("object of type 'float' has no len()", 'occurred at index 247')

Comment: Sounds like not all values in `row['do']` are strings.  Instead you have some floats in there as well.  So you can simply do `if len(str(row['do'])) < 4` or you can force all values in the `do` column to be strings before you try and process each row.

Comment: @ChrisDecker yeah. looks like you have some `object` type column with mixed types, some are string, some a float at least. Without a [mcve], which you should be providing, it's impossible to say.

Comment: In my experience, that float is generally `nan`.

Comment: TheF1rstPancake's fix worked, I had som NaNs in my column. Sorry guys, still new to python and sometimes overlook the basics. Thank you for your help.